# How to angle wifi antenna on client device relative to line of sight to the AP?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, antenna

I have a wifi AP and a network camera some distance away (https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31s5oAd3j%2BL._AC_.jpg ). The network camera has 2 antennas which can be pointed in different directions. The AP has no visible (movable) antennas.  Relative to the line defined by the AP and the camera, how should the antennas be pointed? In other words, should I point an antenna directly toward the AP, or perpendicular to that, or something else?

Comment: Perhaps this is a Physics.SE question!

Comment: What type are the camera's antennas? Are they omnidirectional like an AP's? Do you have photos and/or model numbers?

Comment: It looks like this:   https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/31s5oAd3j%2BL._AC_.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That kind of antenna radiates in a flat disk shape out the sides of the stick. Much less power goes out the "ends" of the stick. So you want the sides of the stick to face the AP. You definitely don't want to point the stick at the AP like you would point a finger, because that would provide the worst coverage.

The typical plastic stick antennas on many Wi-Fi APs (wireless routers) and on the camera in the picture you posted, is a plastic shell protecting an omnidirectional dipole antenna. Please note that in antenna terminology, "omnidirectional" means equal coverage in all  360° of a flat disk, not a full 3D sphere. Equal coverage across an entire 3D sphere is called "isotropic".

Generally, it's not safe to say much about the RF characteristics of an antenna you can't see (the plastic shell conceals the actual metal antenna inside), and even a seasoned antenna engineer wouldn't want to say too much about an antenna they *can* see without testing it first, but these cheap, relatively low-gain omnidirectional dipoles are so common in the Wi-Fi industry that it's pretty safe, when seeing a short stick like that, to assume it's something like a 3dB omnidirectional dipole.